# how to disable window close button in OSX using wxpython?

Tags: macos, wxpython

i am working on an application for osx using wxpython. I want to minimize window to dockbar when user clicks on the window close button so that it can be restored from the dockbar. How can i do that? Currently i am having problem restoring window because it gets destroyed when user clicks on the close button. how can i prevent that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The way I do it is like this:

In the `__init__` method set up handlers for the `wx.EVT_CLOSE` event and a menu item that is your "real" quit option.  You need this or you can never close your program.

```
def OnClose(self,evt):
  #Turn closes into hides unless this is a quit application message / or OS shutting down
  if evt.CanVeto():
    self.Hide()
    evt.Veto()
  else:
      #if we don't veto it we allow the event to propogate
      evt.Skip() 

def OnMenuExit(self,evt):
  #Event handler for exit menu item
  self.Close(force=True)  #Stops the close handler vetoing it
```

You should also make sure that in `__init__` you call `wx.App.SetMacExitMenuItemId( [ID OF YOUR EXIT MENU ITEM HERE] )`  so that the quit item in your dock context menu routes to your correct menu handler.

This gives you a nice mac-ish hide when the window is closed. You need to be aware that the app is still runnning and its menus can be called as the menu bar is still in the top of the  screen.   Strategic calls to `self.Show()` in menu event handlers are your friend here.

You can also make good use of wx.TaskBarIcon to interact nicely with the dock when your app window is hidden (e.g. click on dock to reshow window).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just bind the event `EVT_CLOSE` and minimize instead of closing using your handler for `EVT_ICONIZE`

```
...
def __init__(self):
  ...
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onCloseWindow)
  ...
def onCloseWindow(self, event):
  ... do something else instead of closing ...
...
```